# Will any JS minifiers replace common property names with strings?

Tags: javascript, minify

Will any JS minifiers (uglify, closure, etc) go through the step of adding a variable for long property names?  I've tried both and can't find flags to do this, but just wondering if anyone knows something I don't :)

e.g.:

```
obj.longPropertyName = 42;
obj.longPropertyName++;
obj.longPropertyName++;
obj.longPropertyName++;
```

could be minified to:

```
var a='longPropertyName';
obj[a]=42;
obj[a]++;
obj[a]++;
obj[a]++;
```

[edit] To be clear, closure will do this (or rather it will reduce to `obj.a`), but it won't with default props like `window.addEventListener`

Comment: There may be a performance penalty in converting `obj.prop` to `obj['prop']` so I would venture that most minifiers avoid it. And I've only seen the other way around where 'obj['prop'] is converted to `o.prop` because it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some minifier have the additional flag to **obfuscate** function- and property-names. Mostly, those obfuscations lead to very short property names (but not every time).

EDIT: The YUI compressor for example will do this by default, if you don't pass the --nomunge argument to it.

Comment: I've never seen one do it when it doesn't have control over the declaration though.  e.g. `window.addEventListener`